# Avoid application expanding to support iPhone X

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit

I recently converted my game to Swift 4, and it automatically expanded it when running on the iPhone X so some of it is cut off by the notch. Is there a way to shrink it back down for the iPhone X to make it look like it did when it didn't support it?

I am using the SpriteKit framework

Comment: awkward question: _why?_

Comment: @holex becuase the expansion cuts off some parts of the game, and the borders are black anyway so the way it was before looked normal

Comment: how about using the safe-areas as it should?

Comment: It’s a SpriteKit application so it doesn’t use the storyboard. I tried shrinking the frame of the view but it didn’t work

Comment: the safe-areas are __not__ exclusively for storyboards; those are available on iOS11 in general, for e.g. sprite-kit apps as well, why don't you just update your app for safe-areas then? it is still not clear to me _why_ that is not an option here.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest let it scale the view to cover the notch. But you can make a small change to prevent the notch covering the actual view.

Place your actual game view inside the safe-area in the storyboard, or if using constraints to set the view, use safe-area-insets to align it with the notch.

If you any how want to shrink the app back to its original size, UNCHECK the USE AUTO LAYOUT & USE SAFE AREA LAYOUT GUIDES from the FILE INSPECTOR in storyboard.